# Issue when using v-bind to update star value in semantic ui using vue.js rendering

Tags: vue.js, semantic-ui

I am using semantic-ui and vue.js and below is a simple code in which I am running a vue.js for-loop which is fetching merchant, clicked and rating values. The code is working fine except for {{item.rating}}. The thing is although I am getting the numeric value for my rating but somehow it is not updating my "ui star rating" (please see the screenshot. It looks like it is not updating the default value of "initialRating" which is 3 to the value which I want to push. Not sure how to resolve this.

```
<div id="vue-app" class="ui four doubling cards">
    <div id="myList" class="ui small card" v-for="(item, index) in infox" v-show="item.Title">
    <p class="small meta">{{ item.Merchant }}</p>
        <p class="meta"><i class="mouse pointer icon"></i>{{item.Clicked}} clicked today</p>
        <div class="ui star rating" v-bind:data-rating="{{item.Rating}}"></div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.ui.rating')
    .rating({
    initialRating: 3,
    maxRating: 5});
</script>
```

Screenshot of my issue
[image]

Comment: Reactivity is not compatible with jQuery. You can write this functionality in Vue or use ready-made solutions, e.g. [vue-star-rating](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-star-rating)

Comment: @Gander, when you say "write this functionality in vue", what do you exactly mean here ?

Comment: @fear_matrix When your page is rendered, your `rating` jQuery extension takes the value of `data-rating` and creates the star rating with this. Whatever happens later to the value is ignored by the `rating` jQuery extension. I'd suggest you check your `rating` extension if it supports `refreshing` and trigger the refreshing function from vue (whenever your `item.Rating` changes). If you need addiontnal help, just let us know which rating Extension you use.

Comment: @Gander I am using semantic.min.js ( "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js") and more details how I am using semantic ui rating is given in this URL "https://semantic-ui.com/modules/rating.html#/examples". I am just initializing .ui.rating in my javascript and calling it via "ui star rating". There is nothing extra I am doing.

Comment: @fear_matrix, try to do as MarcDix wrote, to cause Vue to refresh the stars. If that doesn't work, try either using the component that I gave the link to earlier or write your own vue component. jQuery does not work like Vue, and when it is run (whether it is a function or specific CSS classes), it will override the effect of Vue.

Comment: I have resolved the issue. Thanks @MarcDix

Comment: Thanks @Gander for your help.

Comment: @fear_matrix I don't see this green tick indicating that the answer is the solution. Are you sure you marked your own answer as a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is now resolved. Apparently what I did was that i inserted the semantic ui's ".ui.rating" function in my vue method just after the axios api call. So it means that after my axios.get is executed then my ".ui.rating" calls gets initialized everytime when I call loadmore.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    data: {
      dino: d_var,
      infox: [],
      isHidden: false
    },
    methods: {
      loadmore: function () {
        axios.get(this.dino)
          .then(response => {
            this.infox.push(...response.data);
            this.dino = "/api/search/" + this.infox[this.infox.length - 1].lid;
            kk = this.infox[this.infox.length - 1].gr;
            jj = ("true" == kk);
            this.isHidden = jj;
          })
          .then(function () {
            $('.ui.rating')
              .rating({
                initialRating: 3,
                maxRating: 5
              });
          })
      }
    },

  })
```